# cmake: "make install" does not link against libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, gnu-make

I am relatively new to `CMake`, and I have developed a small project which builds a library that links to a shared library, named `external_library`. My `CMakeLists.txt` file looks something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(project_name)

include_directories(path_to_external_library_source_code)
add_subdirectory(path_to_external_library_header_files subproject/external_library)

target_link_libraries(project_name external_library)
install(TARGETS project_name DESTINATION installation_path)
```

When I build the project (using `make`), it works perfectly, and it creates the links correctly (I have checked it with the `ldd` command). However, when I try to install it (with `make install`), the generated file in the installation path is not linked against the specified shared library.

Using `ldd` again, I have checked that the shared library is not found by the library generated in the installation path, although it is found in the library generated in the build path. How could I fix this?

Thanks.

Pd: I am using `CMake 3.5.1` in `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

Comment: What do you think `add_subdirectory(path_to_external_library_header_files subproject/external_library)` does? Is there a CMakeLists.txt file in `path_to_external_library_header_files`? Why are you trying to bulld the external library as part of tyour project?

Comment: Yes, there is a `CMakeLists.txt` in `path_to_external_library_header_files` which adds the `.cpp` and the `.h` files of the shared library to the project.

Comment: I want the shared library to be part of the created library, that is why I use `add_subdirectory` (I hope I am doing it right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem can be solved using the command `find_library`, specifying the path of the built shared library, doing something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(project_name)

include_directories(path_to_external_library_source_code)
find_library(LIBNAME LibName_1 LibName_2 HINTS built_lib_directory)    

target_link_libraries(project_name ${LIBNAME})
install(TARGETS project_name DESTINATION installation_path)
```

Answer (score 8):

Shared libraries are looked for in certain paths, configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

If your shared library is in one of these paths, it should be found. If it is *not* in one of these paths, you have four options:

1. *Having* the library installed in a system default path (which might not be desirable with experimental software, or even possible given your permissions);
2. edit the system-wide search path (not really desirable to touch system-wide settings, and perhaps not possible due to permissions),
3. setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (not recommended as it overrides system search paths, it's a debugging feature basically), or
4. setting an RPATH, i.e. "telling" / "hardcoding" the binary where to look for its library.

What happens is that CMake *automatically* sets the RPATH of your binary, to reference the shared library *from your project build* in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. (You want to test the binary against the library you just built, not the one you installed yesterday.)

By default, this RPATH setting is *cleared* by `make install` (so the library in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` is no longer referenced, and instead searched for in the system search path).

Assuming that you are installing to a destination that is *not* in the system search path, your binary now no longer "sees" its shared library. Consult  [CMake RPATH handling](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling)
 to have CMake set the RPATH of your binaries to the installation path of your shared library.